# How can I get this Eval to work in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I only want to show the credit card info section if the Eval expression evaluates to true, but it gives me and error saying I can only use it in the context of a databinding control, I know I have to put the #, but vb then says that I must use If() or IIF().  What is the correct syntax.

```
 <% If Eval("DisplayCreditCardInfo") Then%>
       <tr>
             <td align="right"><b>Credit Card Type:</b></td>
             <td><%#Eval("CreditCardType")%></td>
             <td align="right"><b>Name on Credit Card:</b></td>
             <td><%#Eval("CreditCardHolder")%></td>
             <td align="right"><b>Billing Address:</b></td>
             <td><%#Eval("CreditCardBillingAddress")%></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
             <td align="right"><b>Credit Card Number:</b></td>
             <td><%#Eval("CreditCardMaskedPan")%></td>
             <td align="right"><b>Expiry Date:</b></td>
             <td><%#Eval("CreditCardExpireDate")%></td>
             <td align="right"><b>CVV:</b></td>
             <td><%#Eval("CreditCardSecurityCode")%></td>
        </tr>
 <% End If %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<% If Eval("DisplayCreditCardInfo") Then%>
```

should be

```
<% If DisplayCreditCardInfo() Then%>
```

Assuming that DisplayCreditCardInfo is a Function in code-behind.

Comment: DisplayCreditCardInfo is a column in a table, but I also tried <% If ShowCreditCardInfo(Eval("DisplayCreditCardInfo")) %>, but this complains as well.